# React Native TextInput type="numeric" but defaultValue Must be String

Tags: react-native

In my React Native app I have a TextInput with `type="numeric"`. When the page loads I get a number value from the server that I was to prepopulate in the TextInput using `defaultValue`.

```
const [ val, setVal ] = useState(100)


<TextInput
  defaultValue={val}
  onChange={setVal}
  type="numeric"
  value={val}
/>
```

This will throw an error saying `defaultValue` can only be a string or undefined.

- Am I suppose to set the value from the server to a string and then set it back to number before sending it to the server?
- If I have `type="numeric"` set won't that mix numbers and strings together? Or are the numbers still just in a string?
- Why doesn't RN allow for a number as `defaultValue`?

Answer (score 1):

I've wondered this myself. It might have to do with differences between javascript and whatever language ( eg Java/Kotlin/Swift) number types. I would think that there would be a number type that is similar to javascript's number (in java I think this would be `double` or maybe `float`), but because `TextInput` doesn't support it I assume that things arent as easy as they seem.

If you want your state to remain the number type, just cast to number in `onChangeText`, and use `toString()` for `value` and `defaultValue`.

```js
<TextInput
  defaultValue={val.toString()}
  onChange={text=>{
     const num = parseFloat(text)
    // Make sure user havent found a way
    // to overcome the numeric keyboard limitations
    if(isNaN(num)){
      console.log(text)
      return
    }
    setVal(num)
  }}
  type="numeric"
  value={val.toString()}
/>
```